# How to relate memory usage with occupied positions of SparseArrays?

Tags: memory, sparse-arrays

What is the relation of memory usage of a `SparseArray` and the number of its occupied positions?

Let's say you build a $100000000 \times 10$ `SparseArray` and fill the two positions $(1,1)$ and $(100000000,10)$ with a value:

```
num = 999999;  
idSparse = SparseArray[{{1, 1} -> num, {100000000, 10} -> num}]
```

There are two elements in the array.

Memory usage is:

```
ByteCount[idSparse]  
  400000968
```

Disk usage is:

```
Export["idSparse.rsa", idSparse];  
FileByteCount["idSparse.rsa"]  
  380
```

Answer (score 9):

Looking at the `InputForm` or `FullForm` of the expression which, while not equivalent to the internal data format, shows something of the structure and what is stored:

```
SparseArray[{{1, 1} -> 999, {5, 100} -> 999}] // InputForm
```

> ```
> SparseArray[Automatic, {5, 100}, 0, {1, {{0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2}, {{1}, {100}}}, {999, 999}}]
> ```

versus:

```
SparseArray[{{1, 1} -> 999, {100, 5} -> 999}] // InputForm
```

> ```
> SparseArray[Automatic, {100, 
>   5}, 0, {1, {{0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
>     1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
>      1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
>     1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2}, {{1}, {5}}}, {999, 999}}]
> ```

shows that some limited data is stored for every *row* in the array.

Therefore your expression will take up much less space if it is entered as:

```
num = 999999;
idSparse = SparseArray[{{1, 1} -> num, {10, 100000000} -> num}];
ByteCount[idSparse]
```

> 784

Of course your program will need to account for the changed orientation.

Comment: Good find, didn't know that.

Comment: OK.  .  .Very good.  .  .We may add that in the first way we get large a RAM and a small file, the second way we get a smal RAM usage and a large file.

Comment: @HpR that's good information, but not very convenient.  I wonder if there is another sparse array file format that matches *Mathematica*'s behavior.  Using `Transpose` on the small-type SparseArray makes it large (as expected), so that is not a solution.

Comment: N.B. peering through the internal form of `SparseArray[]` quickly reveals that the storage format is the so-called ["row-major" or Yale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#Compressed_sparse_row_.28CSR.2C_CRS_or_Yale_format.29) format.

Comment: @J.M. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, a two-dimensional `SparseArray` is stored in the CSR format (CSR = Compressed Sparse Row(-major)). Let's suppose you store an $m \times n$ matrix with $k$ nonzero entries. The actual data stored is

1. an $m+1$-vector of `Integers`, the so-called *row pointers*;
2. a $k$-vector of `Integer`, the so-called *column indices*;
3. a $k$-vector of the *nonzero values*; typically, the entries are `Integer`s, `Real`, `Complex`s. But it can be what ever you want;
4. a $2$-vector storing the dimensions as `Integer`s.

Mathematica's `Integers` are 64 bit = 8 byte in size (unless they are too large for 64 bit; then some other representation is chosen). Machine-precision `Real`s are 64 bit = 8 byte, too.

So roughly, the actual size should be

```
size = 8 (m+1) + 8 k + 8 k + 8 2
```

or

```
size = 8 (Length[A["RowPointers"]] + Length[A["ColumnIndices"]] + Length[A["NonzeroValues"]] + Length[A["Dimensions"]])
```

When I compare that with `ByteCount[A]`, then get fairly the same number.
The actual size `ByteCount[A]` is a couple of hundred bytes greater because each of theconstituting arrays probably its own dimensions (which are redundant, but not a big issue). Moreover, probably some meta-information and flags (for example for remembering that a matrix is symmetric) are also stored in the data structure. Maybe some padding, too, for data alignment. Oh, and I forgot to count in one copy of the default element. ;)

As you can see, there is always an array of size $m+1$ stored no matter how few nonzero entries there are. That's why it might be a good idea to store tall and skinny matrices in transposed form. The catch is that multiplying a sparse matrix with a vector *from the right* is typically a bit less expensive than multiplying the vector from the left to the transposed matrix. This has to do with the asymmetry in the CSR format.