# Largest matrix size supported by Mathematica 10

Tags: matrix, memory, system-limitations

I have need to store large square matrices in memory, some times sparse, some times not. I have used up to $2^{15}$ by $2^{15}$ as my upper bound so far, and Mathematica has handled it even if it took quite a while :).

I would like to try to do some calculations on a $2^{20}$ by $2^{20}$ now, but it will take quite a long time to compute... so I need to know in advance if Mathematica will be able to handle that much memory use. Answers for both sparse and dense cases are encouraged.

Comment: A $2^{15}$ dense square matrix takes 8GB of RAM. A $2^{20}$ one takes 8TB. Do you have that much RAM? I think *Mathematica* should be able to handle it, if your OS can. However, I've never tested this, as the biggest computer I have access to has only 4TB of RAM, and *Mathematica* isn't available on it.

Comment: @OleksandrR. where do you get a computer that has that much physical RAM? I want one, or two ... dozen.

Comment: @rcollyer the cheapest way is probably to get 32 computers each with 256GB of RAM, connect them together using 40Gbit/s Infiniband, and install [vSMP](http://www.scalemp.com/products/product-comparison/) on them. Alternatively you could buy an [SGI UV](http://www.sgi.com/products/servers/uv/).

Comment: @OleksandrR. here I was hoping you could get a single motherboard with that much RAM, but alas, 512GB seems to be the [limit](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813182674).

Comment: @rcollyer 32GB DIMMs also tend to be substantially more expensive per GB than 16GB. That's why I suggested 256GB per computer rather than 512GB.

Comment: The other thing is, many matrix operations have a complexity of between $O(N^2)$ and $O(N^3)$. So, be prepared for your calculation with the $2^{20}$ matrix to take several (tens of) thousands of times longer than "quite a while".

Comment: @OleksandrR. Thanks for all the insight!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Oleksandr remarked on the memory required for a dense matrix.  I shall attempt to explore `SparseArray` limitations.

From this error message it appears that the dimensions of the array must be machine integers:

```
SparseArray[{}, {2, 2}^70]
```

> SparseArray::adims: Array dimension specification {1180591620717411303424,1180591620717411303424} should be Automatic, a non-negative machine integer, or a list of non-negative machine integers. >>

If smaller dimensions are used it may still take too much memory:

```
SparseArray[{}, {2, 2}^60]
```

```
No more memory available.
Mathematica kernel has shut down.
Try quitting other applications and then retry.
```

From [earlier experimentation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25641/121) I determined that every *row* in the arrays takes significant memory, so if we limit the number of rows:

```
SparseArray[{}, {2^20, 2^63 - 2}] // ByteCount
```

> ```
> 8389184
> ```

*Mathematica* is easily able to address a sparse array with *2^20* rows and on my machine up to *2^63 - 2* columns.  However transposing this array would be impossible.

While we can assemble a `SparseArray` of this size with some non-zero elements:

```
rls = 
 Array[
   Round[RandomReal[1, 2]*{2^20, 2^63 - 2}] -> # &,
   1000
 ];

test = SparseArray[rls, {2^20, 2^63 - 2}];
```

and some fundamental operations are possible:

```
3*test // ByteCount
```

> ```
> 8405720
> ```

others operations are not:

```
SparseArray[{1 -> 2, 7 -> 14, 183 -> 99}, 2^20].test
```

```
No more memory available.
Mathematica kernel has shut down.
Try quitting other applications and then retry.
```