# Dataset is 20X slow when adding column heads

Tags: performance-tuning, dataset, sorting

I'm trying to use `Dataset` to explore some large data. I notice that the performance decrease more than 20X by adding heads to the columns. Here is an example:

We generate some data with integers

```
data = RandomInteger[{1, 100000}, {1000000, 7}];
```

convert it into a Dataset object

```
ds1 = Dataset[data]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.000606, Null} *)
```

and sort it according to the first column

```
ds1[SortBy[#[[1]] &]]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.507638, Null} *)
```

Now if we add the heads to the data

```
head = "x" <> ToString[#] & /@ Range[7]
(* {"x1", "x2", "x3", "x4", "x5", "x6", "x7"} *)
ds2 = Dataset[AssociationThread[head -> #] & /@ data]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {4.57311, Null} *)
```

Now sorting becomes 20X slower

```
ds2[SortBy[#x1 &]]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {10.6259, Null} *)
```

So why does the performance decrease when we add a header to our data? Is there a way to fix that?

System information:
version 11.1 on mac os 10.12.3

Comment: It seems this takes longer; `ds2[SortBy[#"x1" &]]; // AbsoluteTiming`. And this takes even longer; `ds2[SortBy[#["x1"] &]]; // AbsoluteTiming`.  Very curious. v 11.1 Win 8.1 Pro

Comment: @Edmund I wouldn't say this is so peculiar. Look at the overhead introduced by the headers -- they are added to every row, because named columns are associations. If you do `ByteCount` (I know it isn't perfect), you will see factor 20 difference in size. Very inefficient. You can't really work with big data sets and use `Dataset` with named columns etc. -- you have to use simple lists, otherwise that overhead would eat all the space on your machine before you even started processing it.

Comment: @Stitch Yes. Reading your comment I do remember that at one of the WTCs the fellow who coded `Dataset` did mention that they were looking into ways to not repeat the `Association` `Keys` in every row. I think it would be a challenge in the general case because of the free-form construction.  Maybe some sort of packed dataset will be introduced for regularly structured datasets at some point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `ds2` is a highly inefficient shape.  Using 10 in place of 1000000 in the `data` code we get something like:

*(Observations made in Mathematica 10.1)*

```
ds2 // InputForm

Dataset[{<|"x1" -> 10, "x2" -> 4, "x3" -> 8, "x4" -> 3, "x5" -> 6, 
   "x6" -> 5, "x7" -> 5|>, <|"x1" -> 2, "x2" -> 9, "x3" -> 6, "x4" -> 10, 
   "x5" -> 10, "x6" -> 5, "x7" -> 1|>, <|"x1" -> 9, "x2" -> 6, "x3" -> 6, 
   "x4" -> 10, "x5" -> 2, "x6" -> 10, "x7" -> 6|>, 
  <|"x1" -> 8, "x2" -> 2, "x3" -> 2, "x4" -> 2, "x5" -> 6, "x6" -> 2, 
   "x7" -> 8|>, <|"x1" -> 1, "x2" -> 8, "x3" -> 10, "x4" -> 3, "x5" -> 8, 
   "x6" -> 3, "x7" -> 9|>, <|"x1" -> 3, "x2" -> 6, "x3" -> 1, "x4" -> 10, 
   "x5" -> 3, "x6" -> 5, "x7" -> 8|>, <|"x1" -> 6, "x2" -> 7, "x3" -> 5, 
   "x4" -> 2, "x5" -> 10, "x6" -> 4, "x7" -> 9|>, 
  <|"x1" -> 7, "x2" -> 10, "x3" -> 8, "x4" -> 1, "x5" -> 3, "x6" -> 3, 
   "x7" -> 8|>, <|"x1" -> 4, "x2" -> 3, "x3" -> 6, "x4" -> 1, "x5" -> 8, 
   "x6" -> 5, "x7" -> 1|>, <|"x1" -> 8, "x2" -> 7, "x3" -> 8, "x4" -> 1, 
   "x5" -> 3, "x6" -> 9, "x7" -> 10|>}, TypeSystem`Vector[
  TypeSystem`Struct[{"x1", "x2", "x3", "x4", "x5", "x6", "x7"}, 
   {TypeSystem`Atom[Integer], TypeSystem`Atom[Integer], 
    TypeSystem`Atom[Integer], TypeSystem`Atom[Integer], 
    TypeSystem`Atom[Integer], TypeSystem`Atom[Integer], 
    TypeSystem`Atom[Integer]}], 10], <|"ID" -> 127397422492264|>]
```

Not only is this redundant but its form prohibits [packing](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3496/121); every `Integer` is stored separately.

Compare the [`Transpose`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Transpose.html) of your `ds2`:

```
ds2\[Transpose] // InputForm

Dataset[<|"x1" -> {10, 2, 9, 8, 1, 3, 6, 7, 4, 8}, 
  "x2" -> {4, 9, 6, 2, 8, 6, 7, 10, 3, 7}, 
  "x3" -> {8, 6, 6, 2, 10, 1, 5, 8, 6, 8}, 
  "x4" -> {3, 10, 10, 2, 3, 10, 2, 1, 1, 1}, 
  "x5" -> {6, 10, 2, 6, 8, 3, 10, 3, 8, 3}, 
  "x6" -> {5, 5, 10, 2, 3, 5, 4, 3, 5, 9}, 
  "x7" -> {5, 1, 6, 8, 9, 8, 9, 8, 1, 10}|>, 
 TypeSystem`Struct[{"x1", "x2", "x3", "x4", "x5", "x6", "x7"}, 
  {TypeSystem`Vector[TypeSystem`Atom[Integer], 10], 
   TypeSystem`Vector[TypeSystem`Atom[Integer], 10], 
   TypeSystem`Vector[TypeSystem`Atom[Integer], 10], 
   TypeSystem`Vector[TypeSystem`Atom[Integer], 10], 
   TypeSystem`Vector[TypeSystem`Atom[Integer], 10], 
   TypeSystem`Vector[TypeSystem`Atom[Integer], 10], 
   TypeSystem`Vector[TypeSystem`Atom[Integer], 10]}], 
 <|"Origin" -> HoldComplete[AssociationTranspose, 
    Dataset`DatasetHandle[127397422492264]]|>]
```

Observe that not only is the representation more compact but the data is typed as vector arrays: `` TypeSystem`Vector[TypeSystem`Atom[Integer], 10] ``.

Create your `Dataset` in the efficient shape to begin with to avoid a very slow `Transpose` operation:

```
ds3 = Dataset @ AssociationThread[head -> (data\[Transpose])];
```

From here you can quickly apply a sort like this:

```
ds3[[All, ds3["x1", Ordering] // Normal]]; // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
> {0.183, Null}
> ```

**Note:** This `Ordering` uses *only* the `"x1"` data and therefore the output will be similar to the [stable](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7687/121) `SortBy[{#x1 &}]` rather than the tie-breaking `SortBy[#x1 &]`.  My *guess* is that this is actually what you will want most of the time.  If a full tie-breaking form is *required* then:

```
ds3[[All, ds3[Values] // Normal // Transpose // Ordering]]; // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
> {0.320, Null}
> ```

---

The dependence on shape in `Dataset` is similar to the case of [`SparseArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray.html); see:

- [How to relate memory usage with occupied positions of SparseArrays?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25641/121)

Comment: I have to give a heart-warm warning to the future reader here :),the package ``TypeSystem` `` has been abandoned after version *10.3* (maybe).

Comment: @yode How does my code perform in more recent versions?

Comment: Just render my screen with red,the ``TypeSystem`* `` cannot work here.Look the suitation in [11.1](https://ooo.0o0.ooo/2017/04/02/58e0bff4043a6.jpg)

Comment: @gwr Just too poor to upgrade with every release. :-/

Comment: @Mr.Wizard ... given your abilities? ; ). But with Mathematica we probably simply bet on the wrong horse: The only person that has gotten rich using and selling Mathematica is a physicist in Illinois... :-\ There seems to be negligible direct demand in industry from what I see. If it weren't' so darn fun to use it.