# How could I see the memory use on sparse array and constant array matrices? What is the advantage?

Tags: linear-algebra, memory, sparse-arrays

I have a huge matrix defined using constant array function and it allocates so much memory preventing the calculation. Therefore, I would like to change the constant array matrix into sparse matrix which stores only nonzero elements enables reducing the memory size.

Here is just a simple example. Let's say I have a constant array `deneme` and convert it into sparse matrix `deneme2` as below:

```
deneme = ConstantArray[0, {3, 3}];


deneme[[1, 1]] = 6; deneme[[1, 2]] = 3; deneme[[1, 3]] = 5; 
deneme[[2, 1]] = 4; deneme[[2, 2]] = 7; deneme[[2, 3]] = 8; 
deneme[[3, 1]] = 1; deneme[[3, 2]] = 5; deneme[[3, 3]] = 9;


deneme2 = SparseArray[deneme];
```

**How could I see the total memory the two matrices, `deneme` and `deneme2` allocate?**

**Does `ByteCount` work correctly, since the sparse matrix stores much more byte than constant array matrix ?**

Comment: Did you try searching the documentation? Didn't you come across `ByteCount`? . Try `ByteCount/@ {deneme, deneme2}`. Does this answer your question? [How to relate memory usage with occupied positions of SparseArrays?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25641/how-to-relate-memory-usage-with-occupied-positions-of-sparsearrays)

Comment: @rhermans, thank you for your suggestion. However, does ByteCount work correctly, since the sparse matrix stores much more byte than constant array matrix ? I know that sparse matrix stores less memory ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could have found in the documentation a section about [Memory Measurement & Optimization](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/MemoryMeasurementAndOptimization.html).

[image]

The first entry is `ByteCount`.

To measure the memory use you can [`Map`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html) [`ByteCount`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ByteCount.html) over a list of the cases of interest.

```
ByteCount/@ {deneme, deneme2}
```

In your case you will find there is no memory use advantage. Why?

[`SparseArray`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray.html) has an overhead, and it will use more or less memory depending on the size of the matrix and how sparse the representation really is.

You are defining a very small matrix that is not very sparse at all.

Here I create a reasonably sparse matrix using [`SparseArray`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray.html).

[image]

Then I measure [`ByteCount`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ByteCount.html) with and without [`Normal`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Normal.html).

The plot shows how for large matrix there is a significant advantage on storing a `SparseArray`.

```
ListPlot[
    Transpose@Table[
        Map[
            {n, ByteCount[#]}&
            , { Normal[#], # }& @ SparseArray[{{1,1}->9, {i_, j_}/;(i==j-1) -> 1}, {n,n}, 0]
        ]
        ,{n, PowerRange[1,2^14, 2]}
    ]
    , ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"}
    , PlotLegends ->{"Normal", "Sparse"}
    , FrameLabel -> {"Size", "ByteCount"}
    , PlotTheme  -> "Scientific"
    , Joined -> True
    , InterpolationOrder->2
]
```

[image]

```
Show[
    %,
    Plot[
        {8 x^2, 48 x, 160, 1100}
        , {x,1,2^14}
        , ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"}
        , PlotStyle-> Directive[Gray, Opacity[0.25]]
    ]
    , PlotRange->All
]
```

[image]

From the documentation:

> Sparse arrays are typically used for efficient linear algebra where
> most of the entries are zero and for graph adjacency matrices.
>
> A sparse array stores only the positions where there are nonzero
> values, but represents the full array

Therefore, `SparseArray` is not only justified by the storage. Further advantages come on more *efficient linear algebra* operations over `SparseArray`s.